# Files holder application like dropover and yoink for Mac

Tags: linux, files, linux-mint, productivity, drag-and-drop

I've recently switched back from macOS to Linux Mint. The only thing I miss about Mac is having a utility that could hold my files for copying and pasting while I switch between the desktops.

Yoink worked in a way that when you drag a file to a configured area (say left edge) a mini window appears. You can drag your files there and the window stays on that edge even if you are switching between the desktops. You can easily then pick the files and drop where you actually want those.

This helped me in a lot of cases like:

- Drag the file from the browser and the drop in another tab (normally you'd have to first download the file)
- easy copy-pasting files between windows or desktops.

I am starving for a Linux alternative.

Comment: Same for me on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's a desktop app that will help you in it. DropPoint holds your files in a floating window for you. Simply drag files into it, navigate to wherever you want, and drag files out of it. Works across desktops and workspaces also.

Works on Windows, Mac and Linux. Free and Open Source.
Do try it out, share, and leave a star if you like it. Made by me

https://github.com/GameGodS3/DropPoint

Comment: That is wonderful. Thank you for making this great app.

Answer (score -1):

It's not exactly similar but I've been using Telegram's "Saved Message" feature to achieve this.

Comment: That won't help you copy files, only text or links and the like.